# How can I get a user's input when using htaccess/htpasswd?

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, controls, .htpasswd

I want to create a log in system using htaccess and htpasswd file and PHP for the server-side code, but when the user logs in I want to be able to identify that user, so how can I know what the user typed in as their username using PHP code (I assume I won't need to know the password if they've managed to access the restricted page)?

Many thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need the following to get the username that is currently in use for an authenticated session:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```

### rev1

In light of @Ben's comment I've now found the section in the PHP documentation at [HTTP authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) that explains what's going on:

> As of PHP 4.3.0, in order to prevent
>   someone from writing a script which
>   reveals the password for a page that
>   was authenticated through a
>   traditional external mechanism, the
>   PHP_AUTH variables will not be set if
>   external authentication is enabled for
>   that particular page and safe mode is
>   enabled. Regardless, `REMOTE_USER` can
>   be used to identify the
>   externally-authenticated user. So, you
>   can use `_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get that to work, it just returns a empty result.

Comment: @ben - well done. FYI I've now found out why this is - I'll make corrections to the answer for the sake of completion.